# Type casting when passing by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

**UPDATE:**

```
typedef uint16_t UnicodeChar;
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
In this case it might seem to be forbidden to cast because arrays' sizes do not agree. Bet why then it is not working then, for example, I'm passing `u_array` of size 10 (not 20 as previous).

**1.** I have a function like this

```
void func(uint16_t (&pin_code)[10])
{
    // do stuff
}
```

And an array (here UnicodeChar is obviously 16 bit):

```
Unicode::UnicodeChar u_array[20];
```

How should I cast this array to be able to pass it to `func()`?

By the way, this compiles without any error:

```
func((uint16_t (&)[10])u_array);
```

But this doesn't:

```
func(static_cast<uint16_t (&)[10]>(u_array));
```

**2.** Why is that?


**3.** (Generic one) How the type of that array is written? For example `int (*)[10]` is a pointer to an array of 10 integers, `int (&)[10]` is a reference to an array of 10 integers, but the array itself is _____? `int [10]`?

**4.** Am I correct at number **2** when I am trying to cast an `array` type object to `reference` type?

Comment: show the definition of `Unicode::UnicodeChar`

Comment: Actually it's *not* "obvious" that `Unicode::UnicodeChar` is 16 bits.

Comment: Also, what is the reason you want to pass a reference to an array to `func` instead of just a pointer and a length? Or use a standard container such as `std::array` or `std::vector`? Or even use a "size of array" template function? You can't make the array be another array. If you want `func` to modify the *contents* of the array a pointer is good enough.

Comment: re. "Update 2" , start a new question and include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

1. See 4
2. This is a `reinterpret_cast` because "array of 20 UnicodeChar" is being aliased as "array of 10 uint16_t". So `static_cast` does not work. The C-style cast resolve to a `reinterpret_cast` if there is no defined `static_cast` for the source and destination types.
3. `int[10]` is the type of an array of 10 ints.
4. The C++ standard is unclear whether it is allowed to alias a "slice" of an array like this.  But I'd expect it would work. However you could redesign your functions to not require this operation.